# How can I connect the Binding for an ImageSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to include an image of a county seal on my WPF `Window` and bind the source to a `BitmapImage` property, but the image does not display at all. I also want to click on the seal and use a `LeftMouseButtonDown` event to change the first image to seven other images with a two second delay between each change.

I tried the techniques in [this StackOverflow post]([How do I bind an Image Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745696/how-do-i-bind-an-image-source) but I still cannot get the first image to display).

The image definition in the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="imag_CountySeal" Margin="0,60,0,80" Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Source="{Binding ImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay}"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Mouse_Down_Seal"
    Width="165" Height="165" Visibility="Visible" />
```

Class definition with the `ImageSource` property and `PropertyChanged` events:

```
public class CountySeals : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapImage _ImageSource;
    public BitmapImage ImageSource
    {
        get { return _ImageSource; }
        set
        {
            _ImageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageSource"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Logic at the start of the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to set `ImageSource` for the first image:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CountySeals seals;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        seals = new CountySeals();
        seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_l transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(Window_SizeChanged);
        StateChanged += new EventHandler(Window_StateChanged);
        LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Window_LocationChanged);
```

`Mouse_Down_Seal` code in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Mouse_Down_Seal(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_2 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_3 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_4 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_5 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_6 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_7 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_8 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

How can I connect the `Binding` for an `ImageSource`?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=OneWay` on the ImageSource Binding is pointless. `Mode=OneWay` is the default value anyway, and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: As a nother note, you would usually not load the image files from absolute paths. Instead, add the files to your Visual Studio project (e.g. in a project folder named Images). Check if their Build Action is set to Resource (should be the default for image files). Then load them by [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/seal_2 transparent.png"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set seals as your MainWindow DataContext:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    seals = new CountySeals();
    this.DataContext = seals; // <---------
    ... etc ...
```

UPDATE: Your problem with the bitmaps not displaying is a completely separate issue. Your mouse handler is called on the GUI thread but you're then tying that thread up with the `Task.Sleep` commands so it never has a chance to update the image. In fact you'll find your whole application will freeze while this is all going on. You need to assign `ImageSource` and do the sleeps etc in a separate thread...and the correct way to do that in C# is with Tasks (with very, very few exceptions you should never call `Thread.Sleep()` in C#). You'll also need to add code to check if a task is already running, and then cancel it first if so. Something like this should do the trick:

```
private Task DisplayTask;
private CancellationTokenSource CancelSource;

private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // cancel any existing task and wait for it to finish
    if (this.CancelSource != null)
    {
        this.CancelSource.Cancel();
        try
        {
            this.DisplayTask.Wait(this.CancelSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // catches the expected exception here
        }

    }

    // start a new task
    this.CancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.DisplayTask = Task.Run(DisplayImages);
}

private async Task DisplayImages()
{
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_2 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), this.CancelSource.Token);
    seals.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\billw\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Images\seal_3 transparent.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), this.CancelSource.Token);
    ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. That worked to make the first image display. However, in my Mouse_Down_Seal routine, only the last of the seven images was shown after a 12 second delay.  How can I make the window update for each one when the ImageSource changes?

Comment: Thank you Mark for your advice and additional code. That worked great, except I also had to add the line: "seals.ImageSource.Freeze();" after setting each new ImageSource. Without that I got an exception "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject". This was described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361020/error-must-create-dependencysource-on-same-thread-as-the-dependencyobject-even.